# Calculate $\int_1^\infty\frac {1}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac {1}{x^2}
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t\frac{1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_1^t\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{t})\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

This is the answer that I'm supposed to get. I got $-1$, but am confused as to how they're obtaining $1$.

Comment: $\bigg(-\dfrac1\infty\bigg)-\bigg(-\dfrac11\bigg)~=~?$

Answer (score 2):

On the last step, you may write
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac {1}{x^2}\:dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}[-\frac{1}{x}]_1^t=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\left(-\frac{1}{1}\right)=0-(-1)=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy, and I can't believe something as simple as a sign error was causing me all of this frustration. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheSpanglock You are welcome.